# What to return as the minimum element of an empty heap

Tags: java, primitive

I have written this simple code to check weather a binary heap is empty or not. I have problem with **return**.    It can not be: `null`, `void`, or nothing; It should return ***something int***, but I don't know what.  So, what should I put there, if I want to keep this code simple? (I mean not using `Integer` class or `java.lang.Integer`).

```
public int getMinimum() {    
  if (isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Heap is empty"); 
    return;           
  } else
    return data[0];
}
```

Comment: return `-1` or a special value

Comment: The code can return whatever you want.  What is it actually doing?  What is your definition of simple.  In your dataset, is a zero a valid solution?  Maybe -1 would work?  You need to give more details/context.

Comment: It cannot return "-1", since it may confused by "minimum value" of the tree.

Comment: By simple code, I mean not using "Integer class" or `java.lang.Integer`.

Comment: throwing an exception probably what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

throw a exception for invalid value and handle it when calling

```
public int getMinimum() throws Exception {
  if (isEmpty())
      throw new Exception("Heap is Empty");
  else
      return data[0];
}
```

and when getting minimum

```
 try{
    int i = getMinimum();
    System.out.println("Minimum is :" + i);
 }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can only help with elimination... java is not magic. If you declare your function to return an "int", then the compiler will make you return an int. 
Which leaves limited options:

1) throw an exception, and teach your users to use it in combination with 'isEmpty()', e.g.:
if(theHeap.isEmpty()) System.out.println("empty");
else System.out.println(theHeap.getMinimum())

2) use that Integer which you didn't like (I'm guessing, for performance reasons?)

3) find some int value that's not likely to be present in the data, e.g. perhaps you don't expect your heap to ever hold Integer.MIN_VALUE.
If your heap contained doubles, i'd recommend NaN.

That's all that's available in the java syntax, sorry it's not ground braking...

Answer (score 1):

*int* is a primitive and therefore needs to have a value.
If you really want to solve it like this, you need to specify a certain int value that would never appear in the heap. You could also try throwing an exception when heap is empty.

Answer (score 0):

we can simply declare it is "***Integer***" instead of "***int***", so we can return "**null**", as well.

```
public Integer getMinimum(){    
  if(isEmpty())
    return null;           
  else
    return data[0];
}
```